# How to call particular storyboard on app launch based on device type (iphone/ipad)?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have two separate storyboards for iPad and iPhone, they have the same classes, outlets and etc, but different layouts.

I found that I can detect device type on app launch with `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom`, but now I need to call correct storyboard. How do I do that? Am I even on the right direction? All I found related to this problem is like posts made 8-9 years ago so I don't even understand syntax sometimes.
Thanks in advance!

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let iPhoneStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPhone", bundle: nil)
        let iPadStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPad", bundle: nil)

        let type = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
        
        switch type {
        case .phone:
            // need to call something here
        case .pad:
            // need to call something here
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the view controller by `instantiateInitialViewController()` or `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let iPhoneStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPhone", bundle: nil)
        let iPadStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPad", bundle: nil)

        let type = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
        
        switch type {
        case .phone:
            window?.rootViewController = iPhoneStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        case .pad:
            window?.rootViewController = iPadStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mickael! Thanks for your quick reply. Just did it, but still get black blanc screen. Seems like nothing wrong with this code, but maybe I need to change something in info.plist or build settings?

Answer (score 0):

HII can you try to set instantiateViewController to UINavigationController and set identifier like as "Ipad" or "Iphone" and set first controller of storyboard to rootviewcontroller of  UINavigationController and set initial viewcontrolled to UINavigationController like as...

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var window: UIWindow?
 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


  let iPhoneStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPhone", bundle: nil)
  let iPadStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IPad", bundle: nil)

        let type = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
        
        switch type {
        case .phone:
           
         if let IPhone = iPhoneStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IPhone") as? UINavigationController {
                    self.window?.rootViewController = IPhone
                }


        case .pad:

       if let IPad = iPadStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IPad") as? UINavigationController {
                    self.window?.rootViewController = IPad
                }
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }

   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   self.window?.makeKey()

 return true


}
```